# How can i get value from three input text box at time in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get value from three input text box.But i want this three value at a time or in array form.How can i get??
here is my html-

```
 <input style='display:none' value='http://localhost/JSG/upload/Hydrangeas6.jpg'  class='imgstr' name='imgstr[]'type='text>
    <input style='display:none' value='http://localhost/JSG/upload/Jellyfish4.jpg'  class='imgstr' name='imgstr[]'type='text'>
    <input style='display:none' value='http://localhost/JSG/upload/Koala1.jpg'  class='imgstr' name='imgstr[]'type='text'>
```

jquery-

```
 var images = $('.imgstr').val(); //Get value from text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var images = $('.imgstr').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `map` and `get` it.

```
var images = $('.imgstr').map(function(){ return this.value }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = [];

$('input.imgstr').each(function() {
   var thisVal = $(this).val();
   results.push(thisVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".imgstr" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( $( this ).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
for(var i = 0;i < document.getElementByClassName('imgstr').length;i++){

    var images += document.getElementByClassName('imgstr')[i];

}
```

Comment: don't you need the .value

Answer (score 0):

use jquery each to iterate on all 3 textboxes using your class attribute.

```
var combinedValue=null;

$(".imgstr").each(function(){
combinedValue=combinedValue+$(this).val();
});
```